# Check if a point intersects a path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map. on the map I have several regions (departments) loaded. I also have a point and I would like to know if this point intersects in the department with the class "dpto_19".

[image]

https://plnkr.co/edit/3Y1PdZNU0DucIMNOTWJO?p=preview

```
//add the circle on the map
var coordenadas=map.latLngToLayerPoint([coordinates[0].lat,coordinates[0].long]);
    svg.append('circle').attr("cx",position.x)
        .attr("cy", position.y)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill",'red')
        .style('pointer-events', 'all')
        .attr("class",'circulo_mapa')


//add the class each department
var oDeptos=[];
d3.selectAll('.leaflet-interactive').attr("class", function(d,i) { 
  oDeptos.push({"nombre":statesData.features[i].properties.NOMBRE_DPT, "clase":"dpto_"+statesData.features[i].properties.DPTO});        
  return d3.select(this).attr("class") + " " + "dpto_"+statesData.features[i].properties.DPTO; 
})
```

Basically I need to know if a point intersects the region I mentioned. For example if the red circle intersects the path with the class dpto_19 I want it to return a true, otherwise a false
[image]

```
    //real coordinates lat, long
    var point=[coordinates[0].lat,coordinates[0].long];

    //the region with class dpto_19 in statesData.feature is the index 7
    console.log(statesData.features[7])
    console.log(d3.geoContains(statesData.features[7],point))
```

I'm new to d3.js and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: call document.elementFromPoint

Comment: How is this different from your other question [*"check if a circle is inside of a path using d3.js"*](/q/45853198)? What do you want? A *point* or a *circle*? What is the test: *intersects*, *is on* or *is inside*? Please be as specific as possible when describing your problem.

Comment: @altocumulus I think you're right. My other question is duplicated. Basically I need to know if a point intersects the region I mentioned. For example if the red circle intersects the path with the class dpto_19 I want it to return a true, otherwise a false.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you help me please, I have not made it work.

Comment: @altocumulus I updated the topic, and delete the other question. I hope can you help me please..

Comment: @yavg If you are able to extract the GeoJSON object for that region you can use [`d3.geoContains()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoContains) to check if the point is within the region's boundaries.

Comment: @yavg I just realized that you are still on v3 where this method is not available. Sadly, this will be no easy solution. You might want to consider stepping up to v4 or porting the relevant parts of that method to your code.

Comment: @yavg I see no call to document.elementFromPoint in your question so I'm unable to say why code you've not shown me doesn't work.

Comment: @altocumulus I updated the code (look again my plnk), but this function always return me false :( can you help me please..?

Comment: @RobertLongson Your function does not understand how you can help me. I have a region and I want to know if the circle intersects it. This function only receives the position x, y

Comment: repeat the call for all points on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: @RobertLongson Maybe you do not understand what I want to achieve. Or maybe it is me who does not understand you. I have a point in x and y of the circle and I have a path. How to know if the circle intersects it?

Comment: for x in points on circle circumference -> does x intersect the region? if so the circle intersects the region, if not it doesn't.